# Can flexbox css be use to create a vertical and horizontal page overlay message

Tags: css, flexbox

It seems simple enough to centre a message vertically and horizontally using css flexbox but im struggling to use it to create a full page overlay.  The flexbox always pushes other content.  Maybe flex isn't the thing to use and i should stick to older css?

The overlay needs to be display: none; or hidden so that it can be shown at the appropriate time using javascript.

```
<div id="overlay"><span id="overlay-message">No Internet Connection</span></div>
```

Im prepending this html to the body when its needed. I suppose this could be removed instead of hidden and then prepended again when needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose that's what you want.

```css
body {
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  font-family:monospace;
  font-size:24px;
}

p {
    text-indent:40px;
}

#overlay {
  background:magenta;
  height:30vh;
  width:30vw;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  position:fixed;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
}

#overlay::before {
  content:'';
  position:fixed;
  background:transparent;
  height:100vh;
  width:100vw;
  left:-35vw;
}

#overlay-message {
  color:#fff;
  font-family:sans-serif;
  font-size:16px;
  text-align:center;
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="overlay"><span id="overlay-message">No Internet Connection</span></div>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quos aliquam fugit illo voluptates harum ex porro officiis provident, odit quo sed error, assumenda maiores possimus architecto! Rem harum eos obcaecati.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quos aliquam fugit illo voluptates harum ex porro officiis provident, odit quo sed error, assumenda maiores possimus architecto! Rem harum eos obcaecati.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quos aliquam fugit illo voluptates harum ex porro officiis provident, odit quo sed error, assumenda maiores possimus architecto! Rem harum eos obcaecati.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quos aliquam fugit illo voluptates harum ex porro officiis provident, odit quo sed error, assumenda maiores possimus architecto! Rem harum eos obcaecati.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quos aliquam fugit illo voluptates harum ex porro officiis provident, odit quo sed error, assumenda maiores possimus architecto! Rem harum eos obcaecati.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quos aliquam fugit illo voluptates harum ex porro officiis provident, odit quo sed error, assumenda maiores possimus architecto! Rem harum eos obcaecati.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quos aliquam fugit illo voluptates harum ex porro officiis provident, odit quo sed error, assumenda maiores possimus architecto! Rem harum eos obcaecati.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quos aliquam fugit illo voluptates harum ex porro officiis provident, odit quo sed error, assumenda maiores possimus architecto! Rem harum eos obcaecati.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quos aliquam fugit illo voluptates harum ex porro officiis provident, odit quo sed error, assumenda maiores possimus architecto! Rem harum eos obcaecati.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quos aliquam fugit illo voluptates harum ex porro officiis provident, odit quo sed error, assumenda maiores possimus architecto! Rem harum eos obcaecati.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quos aliquam fugit illo voluptates harum ex porro officiis provident, odit quo sed error, assumenda maiores possimus architecto! Rem harum eos obcaecati.</p>
```

With a little javascript, it disappears when you click on it.

```
function hide () {
  document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "none";
} 

document.getElementById("overlay").onclick = function() {hide()};
```

Comment: Wizard. Thats the one.  I'd struggle with that. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```css
body {
  overflow:hidden;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}

#overlay {
  background:magenta;
  height:100vh;
  width:100vw;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
}

#overlay-message {
  color:#fff;
  font-family:sans-serif;
  font-size:40px;
}
```

```html
<div id="overlay"><span id="overlay-message">No Internet Connection</span></div>
```

Is that what you want?

or

```css
body {
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  font-family:monospace;
  font-size:24px;
}

p {
    text-indent:40px;
}

#overlay {
  background:magenta;
  height:30vh;
  width:30vw;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  position:fixed;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
}

#overlay-message {
  color:#fff;
  font-family:sans-serif;
  font-size:16px;
  text-align:center;
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="overlay"><span id="overlay-message">No Internet Connection</span></div>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quos aliquam fugit illo voluptates harum ex porro officiis provident, odit quo sed error, assumenda maiores possimus architecto! Rem harum eos obcaecati.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quos aliquam fugit illo voluptates harum ex porro officiis provident, odit quo sed error, assumenda maiores possimus architecto! Rem harum eos obcaecati.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quos aliquam fugit illo voluptates harum ex porro officiis provident, odit quo sed error, assumenda maiores possimus architecto! Rem harum eos obcaecati.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quos aliquam fugit illo voluptates harum ex porro officiis provident, odit quo sed error, assumenda maiores possimus architecto! Rem harum eos obcaecati.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quos aliquam fugit illo voluptates harum ex porro officiis provident, odit quo sed error, assumenda maiores possimus architecto! Rem harum eos obcaecati.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quos aliquam fugit illo voluptates harum ex porro officiis provident, odit quo sed error, assumenda maiores possimus architecto! Rem harum eos obcaecati.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quos aliquam fugit illo voluptates harum ex porro officiis provident, odit quo sed error, assumenda maiores possimus architecto! Rem harum eos obcaecati.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quos aliquam fugit illo voluptates harum ex porro officiis provident, odit quo sed error, assumenda maiores possimus architecto! Rem harum eos obcaecati.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quos aliquam fugit illo voluptates harum ex porro officiis provident, odit quo sed error, assumenda maiores possimus architecto! Rem harum eos obcaecati.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quos aliquam fugit illo voluptates harum ex porro officiis provident, odit quo sed error, assumenda maiores possimus architecto! Rem harum eos obcaecati.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quos aliquam fugit illo voluptates harum ex porro officiis provident, odit quo sed error, assumenda maiores possimus architecto! Rem harum eos obcaecati.</p>
```

Comment: Thank you for a complete answer.  The later was the one i was looking for.  As this overlay uses display:flex; in order to hide it i would need to remove it with query or something?

Comment: And #overlay is not full page so the content behind is clickable.  These are my only issues.